# sbt - exclude certain dependency only during publish

Tags: scala, sbt, pom.xml, apache-spark

I'm building a utility library that can be used together with one of 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 version of Apache Spark.

Since they are all binary backwards-compatible, I'd like to let the user decide which spark version to use (by manually adding `spark-core` with preferred version as a dependency along with my library), and do not impose any version restriction in the library's POM. Otherwise it will annoy users with dependency eviction warnings.

Is it possible to make sbt omit a library dependency in the published POM while not changing any compilation behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the `provided` configuration is specifically designed for that:

```
libraryDependencies += "org" %% "artifact" % "1.0" % "provided"
```

will put said library on the classpath during compilation, but not in the POM file.

Comment: `provided` does put the dependency in the POM file, with `<scope>provided</scope>`. but I want to completely omit the dependency in the POM.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that. Then you can use [pomPostProcess](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Publishing.html#modifying-the-generated-pom) to remove it "manually" from the POM file. Example here: https://github.com/scala/pickling/blob/03be7e4e41732f5777e1895682d7c44405430ea7/project/Build.scala#L171-L195

Comment: @sjrd / @eed3si9n Can you point to the documentation of the `% "provided"` feature behavior?  I didn't find it searching the combined pages [1].  Is the technique below [2] or the improvement here [3] still needed?
[1] https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Combined+Pages.html
[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/27853219
[3] https://stackoverflow.com/a/51416386

Comment: In any case, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51416386 worked for my situation, if a bit noisy.

Answer (score 9):

The following is the sbt setting I wrote using sjrd's help.

```
import scala.xml.{Node => XmlNode, NodeSeq => XmlNodeSeq, _}
import scala.xml.transform.{RewriteRule, RuleTransformer}

pomPostProcess := { (node: XmlNode) =>
  new RuleTransformer(new RewriteRule {
    override def transform(node: XmlNode): XmlNodeSeq = node match {
      case e: Elem if e.label == "dependency" && e.child.exists(child => child.label == "scope" && child.text == "provided") =>
        val organization = e.child.filter(_.label == "groupId").flatMap(_.text).mkString
        val artifact = e.child.filter(_.label == "artifactId").flatMap(_.text).mkString
        val version = e.child.filter(_.label == "version").flatMap(_.text).mkString
        Comment(s"provided dependency $organization#$artifact;$version has been omitted")
      case _ => node
    }
  }).transform(node).head
}
```